# Simulating a trend

Tags: r, simulation

So I want to create a mock dataset where my outcome (y) is increasing over time and is associated with two covariates x1 and x2. Here is the example:

```
expit<-function(z){1/(1+exp(-(z)))}
year<- factor(sample(c(2005:2014), 1e6, replace = T, 
       prob = rep(0.10, 10)))    
x1<-rbinom(1e6, 1, .15)
x2<- rbinom(1e6, 1, expit(-2+log(2)*x1))
y<- rbinom(1e6, 1, .15 + .35*x1 + .15*x2)
```

I would like to know how I can make y increase over time as a function of the yearly increasing probabilities of x1 and x2. In other words in the ten year span, I want the probabilities of x1 and x2  to increase each year the probability of y by .02.

Any suggestions?

Best,

L

Comment: I think you need to explain this a little bit more. Will `prob = seq(0.02,.2, by=.02)` do the trick?

Comment: @hpesoj626 thanks! I tried make my question clearer. See if now it reads better.

Comment: While your example is very specific, the question itself is quite broad, so being precise would be helpful. E.g., do `x1` and `x2` must be as in your example? And `y`? Everything binary? What are `expit` and `year` for?